# Is it possible to change the signature algorithm of intermediate CA without changing the root CA?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ca, self-signed-certificate

Now I have a self-signed root CA certificate whose signature algorithm is **sha256WithRSAEncryption**. All intermediate CA certificates issued by this root CA have the same signature algorithm which is **sha256WithRSAEncryption**. Is it possible to issue an intermediate CA certificate whose signature algorithm is **ecdsa-with-SHA256** without changing the root CA? I can't find such a way, please give me some advice. It would be better if you could provide me with some reference documents about it. Thank you in advance.

I did some tests and found, the encryption algorithm of the private key will affect the signature algorithm of the root certificate. For example:
If I use this command `openssl genrsa -out private/rootca.rsa2048.key.pem 2048` to generate a private key, the signature algorithm of the newly signed root CA is sha256WithRSAEncryption.
If I use this command `openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out private/interca.ecdsa256.key.pem` to generate a private key, the signature algorithm of the newly signed root CA is ecdsa-with-SHA256.

**It seems it's impossible to use a root CA whose signature algorithm is RSA to issue an intermediate CA whose signature algorithm is ECDSA. Please correct me if I'm wrong.**

By the way, here is the description I found in IBM documents. It seems it's impossible indeed. [https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=customization-updating-signature-algorithm#:~:text=The%20signature%20algorithm%20that%20PKI%20Services%20uses%20to%20sign%20certificates%20must%20be%20based%20on%20the%20key%20type%20of%20the%20CA%20certificate](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=customization-updating-signature-algorithm#:%7E:text=The%20signature%20algorithm%20that%20PKI%20Services%20uses%20to%20sign%20certificates%20must%20be%20based%20on%20the%20key%20type%20of%20the%20CA%20certificate).

> The signature algorithm that PKI Services uses to sign certificates must be based on the key type of the CA certificate.

Comment: This is not programming or development and is offtopic, but yes it is impossible. You can use a plain-RSA root (i.e. not RFC4055 section 3) to issue a child cert signed with either RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 or RSASSA-PSS, and any of several hashes, but not with ECDSA or DSA or EdDSA or Falcon or any other algorithm that isn't RSA. I don't know any real 'reference' for this because it's obvious: the specifications for signing with RSA require an RSA key, and those for ECDSA require an X9-style EC key (which _can_ be used for other _EC_ algorithms -- ECDH and ECMQV -- but not RSA).

Comment: If you're asking "can I create an intermediate CA which has an ECDSA key when the root has an RSA key?", the answer is yes (though it's at least slightly discouraged), but that certificate itself can only be signed using RSA, since the issuing certificate has an RSA key.  It can be signed using a different hash algorithm, but not a different signature algorithm family.

Comment: @bartonjs Thanks for the answer. If the signature algorithm of root CA is RSA, then all the issued sub certificates and leaf certificates ought to be RSA. Is that correct? If I do want to change signature algorithm, I have to change to use another root CA whose private key is ECDSA. Is that correct?

Comment: The signature algorithm of the root doesn't matter, except that since it's self-signed (by definition) it is related to the algorithm family of the root's public key.  So a root with an RSA-based signature has, by definition, an RSA key.  An RSA key can only create RSA signatures.  If you want a root to sign intermediates using ECDSA, then you need a different root that has an appropriate key.  The root's key algorithm has no direct bearing on the leaf certs (if there's an intermediate layer).  An RSA root can sign an ECDSA intermediate which can sign a DSA leaf, etc.